# Smartface define a global variable and usage

Tags: smartface.io

I want to send json data or a variable to Page2 from Page1. My codes as follows. I guess I writing wrong code. I don't know how to do this.

**Page1:**

```js
var value1="test";
var jsonData=[];


jsonData.push("Value1");
jsonData.push("Value2");
jsonData.push("Value3");
```

**Page2**

```js
    var TextBox = new SMF.UI.EditBox({
    
    width:"88%",
    height:"100%",
    left:"22%",
    top:"0%",
    text:"",
    
    
    });



    TextBox.text = Pages.Page1.value1;
    TextBox.text = Pages.Page1.jsonData;


    Pages.Page1.add(TextBox);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add that variable to the Global file and then use it where you wish. Like:

```js
//Global.js
var myVar;

//Page1.js
Label.text = myVar;
//or even change its value
myVar = "Hello";
```

But I am looking for a way of doing this without declaring a global variable too.